# getrange([I][1]) range not found

Tags: google-apps-script

i've figured out the rest of my script, there is just one problem that i can't figure out. If i set the range to "f4" or any direct cell, it works just fine. I can reference [n][0] at various other points in the script, but for some reason it won't let me use it as a range. Any ideas or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

```
    function test(){
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("IMI"));
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
 var invinput = ss.getRange("L16").getValue();
 var iteminput = ss.getRange("J16").getValue();
 for (var n = 0; n<data.length; n ++){ 
 if(iteminput == (data[n][0])) {
ss.getRange("data[n][1]").setValue(data[n][1]+invinput);
   break;
   }}}
```

Comment: Nowhere in the docs is it stated that you can use the getRange() method as it's used in your code. You should either use the a1 notation string or numerical values for building the rectangular grid. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column  The general rule of thumb is to read the documentation first before trying something

Comment: Also, calling getRange() within a loop to populate invidual cells will make your code extremely slow. Use integer numbers to reference the entire grid, then write all values to it in a single call , e.g.  sheet.getRange(upperLeftRow, upperLeftCol, rowSpan, colSpan).setValues(values); More details https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column

Comment: Anton is very patient and friendly with you.please consider reading the apps script documentation before reinventing a personal and non working version of it.Np personal offense but this is IMHO the minimal requirement.

Comment: It works just fine with a direct cell, i was simply asking why i can't use getrange to reference a cell in that form. This is a place to ask for help, after all.

Comment: I am simply asking if there is a work around for what I am trying to do. Which is locate cell in column a that matches the input, then change the value of column B. I am not far off, I am just unable to put together this last piece.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the double quotes. If you use quotes, it must be A1 notation. Change this line:

```
ss.getRange("data[n][1]").setValue(data[n][1]+invinput);
```

to this:

```
ss.getRange(data[n][1]).setValue(data[n][1]+invinput);
```

This assumes your data looks something like this:
[image]